# I want to display data using ORM in django but only a query is being generated on my html webpage

Tags: python, django, orm

I want to display data from the database using ORM in django but only a sqlquery is being generated on my html webpage instead of the data.
can anyone please help me resolve this?

My codes:

views.py

```
def home(request):
    Values = Major.objects.raw('SELECT p.major_cd, m.description FROM percentages as p, major as m WHERE p.major_cd = m.major_cd;')
context = { "Values": Values
    }
    return render(request, "website/index.html" , context )
```

index.html

```
{{ Values }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should iterate your query to get results...

```
{% for v in Values %}
  {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```